# How to store key values of a JSON array of object in an array

Tags: javascript

I've got a JSON array of objects like :

```
x= {"user":[{ "name": "Jhon", "age": "18" }, { "name": "Ted", "age": "20" }]};
```

I would like to store every values of names of each object in a simple array but I don't know how to do that

I know that I can get values of names with `JSON.parse(x)["user][0]["name"]`

So I need how to get the number of objects in my array of objects : `Objects.keys(JSON.parse(x)["users"]).length)`

Comment: What exactly don't you know how to do? Show your progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array#map()
```

```js
const data = {"user":[{ "name": "Jhon", "age": "18" }, { "name": "Ted", "age": "20" }]};
console.log(data.user.map(u=>u.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an array using the map function which takes a callback, and return exactly which property you want from each user object inside the callback. You'll be left with an array of names.

```
const myObject = {"user":[{ "name": "Jhon", "age": "18" }, { "name": "Ted", "age": "20" }]};
const names = myObject["user"].map((user) => {
    return user["name"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to **map** the array of users (x.user) to new collection, getting only the names of the user. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map .

In short:

```
var x = {"user":[{ "name": "Jhon", "age": "18" }, { "name": "Ted", "age": "20" }]};

var y = x.user.map(user => user.name)  // <-- y becomes Array [ "Jhon", "Ted" ]
```